# VLC : How to play/pause with a single mouse click in 2023?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player

I tried to find a solution which does not require installing a plugin. VLC preferences do not have the options mentioned in the existing answers so how do you do it in 2023?

Edit: I decided to use SMPlayer for audio files as well. So that's how I did it.

Edit 2: SMPlayer is perfect for audio but it kept resizing the window transitioning between audido only and video files. Tried winamp, however sound was choppy. Finally tried AIMP. After tuning equalizer things are as good as it gets.

Comment: What's wrong with using the spacebar?

Comment: There's an option in the hotkey settings to remap the function but not to LMB. Not sure what kind of other alternative you expect, without even a plugin

Comment: @DavidPostill When I tile a bunch of windows including vlc, it is usually when I am reading and I don't need to use the keyboard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author claimed to use another app in the question, so this is unlikely to be ever resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is old and the author has apparently moved on. But if anyone else is looking for an answer, there's a plugin for versions 2-4 of VLC that provides the functionality the OP originally asked for:

https://github.com/nurupo/vlc-pause-click-plugin

Answer (score 1):

> How to play/pause with a single mouse click

At least three ways:

1. Click the play/pause button.
2. In simple preferences, interface settings, there is "Pause playback when minimized" option. Enable it, save, restart VLC.

   Now the program should pause playback when you minimize the window and unpause when you restore. Clicking the minimize button (or minimizing or restoring from the taskbar) requires a single click, so it counts as "with a single mouse click".
3. Enable [mouse gestures](https://wiki.videolan.org/Mouse_gestures/):

   > To activate this feature, go to Preferences > All > Interface > Control Interfaces and check "Mouse gestures control interface". Then restart VLC.

   Now when VLC plays, press LMB inside VLC playback window, hold it, move the mouse right, then left (xor left, then right), release LMB. The gesture is for pause and for unpause.

Comment: Thanks! Some of the music files I listen to are actually video files so, clicking on the video preview window is much more convenient than a small button and that's what I was looking for. Minimizing is not always a solution, same reason as previous. I tried mouse gestures but for some reason it did not work and I realized this question is being asked for over 10 years yet videolan has not bothered to add this option. SMPlayer is doing a great job so far.

Comment: @paralaks Sigh… "clicking on the video preview window is much more convenient than a small button and that's what I was looking for" – So you should have stated this in the question. For now "with a single mouse click" is the only requirement in this matter, my answer tries to follow it. If you change the question now, you will invalidate my answer. It's inelegant and frowned upon in general, but in this case I can live with that. I'm giving you permission to invalidate my answer. Edit the question and I will delete the answer.

Comment: Oh, I asked this question after searching for a solution for over 30 mins that's why my question said "in 2023". But I understand if someone never had that issue would not think that way. Your answer is valid based on your understanding. No worries :)

Comment: @paralaks "if someone never had that issue would not think that way" – I had, it's irrelevant. *In the future please do not assume we will assume, be explicit.* I answer questions asked, not questions+mind_reading. I've seen genuine questions about allegedly obvious things. Even if the simplest solution here is "click the play/pause button, duh!", I professionally drop the "duh" and provide the solution because it solves the problem stated in the question. I gave all the solutions I know; unfortunately none of them fulfills the hidden requirement you apparently expected readers to guess.

Comment: I am  sorry that you have to live with this Kamil. Just don't take everything in life this seriously. I think it would help.